# ubuntu hangs after installer crashes on setup

Tags: boot

I tried to set up ubuntu 20.04 in my pc.As I selected "install third party software",the installer crashed.now,I want to reinstall it .but pc hangs. I tried shuting down and starting my pc.did not work .here's a picture of the screen after I started my pc .[pc screen on pc start up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wELl1.jpg)

what should i do.?

Comment: Can you press and hold the power button for a few seconds and wait till pc turns off?

Comment: If it doesn't work, wait for the battery to get drained and it will automatically shut down. Try booting. If fails, Live boot using a pendrive with ubuntu 20.04 in it, recover your /home folder and other important stuff and fresh install ubuntu.

Comment: What was the issue when the installer crashed?   If it was *squashfs* errors, you cannot (or should not) trust the installation anyway, so details as to the installer crash should be your first step in my opinion.